# spring framework Error: Context initialization failed

Tags: spring

i am deploying application(spring-hibernate) in tomcat6 but it is giving error-

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: com.myPackage.myProject.calendar.bpo.BusinessDirectoryBPOImpl; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/myPackage/framework/bpo/BaseBPOImpl.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:180)

......
```

all jar files are already in \WEB-INF\lib*.jar.
am i missing any class file or any jar file.
how to solve this error.
Thanks
Yugal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.myPackage.myProject.calendar.bpo.BusinessDirectoryBPOImpl` is looking for

```
com/myPackage/framework/bpo/BaseBPOImpl.class
```

which it cannot find.

Check for sure **if this specific class** is present under `WEB-INF\lib` in a jar or `WEB-INF\classes` as a class file.