# Spring data MongoDb configuration

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

It seems i just can't make this mongoTemplate bean to work in my project :(
Here is my xml for the mongo configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-2.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

<mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="test" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

I added to my project the following files:
mongo-java-driver 2.11.0.jar,spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar,spring-data-mongodb-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar

and of course i installed mongodb on the local server.
here is the exception i'm getting:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-mongoDB.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.<init>(ClassTypeInformation.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.<clinit>(ClassTypeInformation.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper.<clinit>(DefaultMongoTypeMapper.java:45)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1692)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 40 more
Jul 23, 2013 7:52:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-mongoDB.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.<init>(ClassTypeInformation.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.<clinit>(ClassTypeInformation.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper.<clinit>(DefaultMongoTypeMapper.java:45)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1692)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 40 more
Jul 23, 2013 7:52:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Any ideas? Thanks...

Comment: I have org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar in my project as well, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im using spring-core3.0.5 and when i change it to 3.0.7 it works!

Anyone knows if the minimum requirement of the mongoDB spring data support is for spring-core to be 3.0.7??

Comment: Apparently not: See the [requirements](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/requirements.html) in Spring Data MongoDB Documentation.

Comment: Im pretty sure its a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you may have an authentication issue, try specifying the credentials of your mongodb when configuring your db-factory.

I have added my configuration below to clarify

```
<mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="${db.name}" username="${db.username}" password="${db.password}"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I think that you have something else going on with your spring configuration, I do not think that your mongodb configuration is the problem. Unfortunately I am not spring expert so I am not sure what it is, sorry that I could not be more help.

Comment: see these other questions on "Context initialization failed" errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342492/spring-framework-error-context-initialization-failed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382718/context-initialization-failed-or-loading-properties - they may be of some help

Answer (score 1):

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-178?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

They said this cant be fixed as spring upgrade fixed it

Answer (score 1):

In your mongoTemplate you have referred to mongoDBFactory, but you do not have id attribute specified for the factory.

```
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="test" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java config:

```
@Configuration
public class Config(){
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws UnknownHostException{
return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(protocol://username:password@servername/databasename)),"Database_name_here"); //mongodb is the protocol
}    

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws UnknownHostException{
return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory);
}
}
```

When you want to bootstrap this configuration in a main class, you will do that by using Spring's `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` like this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
MongoOperations template = context.getBean(MongoTemplate.class);
```

Then, you will call all the MongoTemplate's methods on MongoOperations's instance.